# Copying The Colors' Values

Tags: cmyk, branding, rgb

I hate when I repeat this task on every Branding project...Copying the colors' values, is there a plugin or an easiest way to export all color values (Spot, CMYK and RGB) to text from the color palette? [image]

Comment: Hey, your link is broken. Would you be so kind to share the working one(modified Col.jsx)?

Answer (score 2):

In **Adobe** apps, yes....

Using the *menu* from the **Swatches Panel** you can save swatches as an **.ase** file (Adobe Swatch Exchange).

In Photoshop....

[image]

In Illustrator....

[image]

In InDesign....

[image]
For InDesign you have to *highlight* the swatches you want to save in the panel first.

Then switch to another Adobe app... and from the **Swatches Panel** again, choose `Load Swatches`, navigate to the saved .ase file and open it. The swatches will load.

- Special swatches, such as gradients and patterns, can *not* be transported between apps. But all solid color swatches are fine whether they are process, spot, or rgb.
- Note that with the exception if InDesign, *all* swatches in the Swatch Panel will be saved (other than gradients and patterns). So, if you want to limit the .ase library, remove any undesired swatches *before* saving as an .ase file.

If working between files in the *same application* you can choose `Load Swatches` and just load *any* other file for that application.

- For example, if you ware working on `DocumentA.indd` in InDesign, you can choose `Load Swatches` and select `DocumentB.indd` to load the swatches from that document.
- Same is true for Illustrator... working on `DocumentA.ai`, choose `Load Swatches` and pick `DocumentB.ai` and all the swatches from Document B will be loaded in Document A.
- This will *not* work with Photoshop though.

Comment: Hey, That was so informative, thanks, but that is not what I wanted.
I want to "extract" colors' values (RGB / CMYK / Hexa) as a TXT file .. 

you see in every branding project you'll have to include these information (color values) in the branding guideline... for that I searched a lot till i found a Script that does that...


called Col.jsx... 

I modified it with a friend of mine.. you can find it here
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6jwFb2pNduwenRSbi05a1hWd2c

it's cool .. 

thanks for your answer btw ^^

Comment: @Designer Too Hey, your link is broken. Would you be so kind to share the working one(modified Col.jsx)?

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this same problem. The best that I have come across thus far is [this](https://carl.camera/sandbox/aseconvert/) online tool that converts your .ase file into a visible format that displays the following:

- the name of each colour
- a sample of each colour
- the hex value of each colour.

This tool is more helpful when the name of each colour is named according to the colour values. In InDesign you can achieve this by:

1. Selecting the colour in the `Swatches panel`.
2. Click on `Swatch Options`.
3. Tick the `Name with Colour Value` checkbox.

If you have done this for all your colours before exporting the .ase file then all the colour values for each colour should display in the online tool above.

Surely there has to be a better way to extract the colour values of colour from a swatch library as text, but for now this is the best I have found.